# Resending woo-commerce order emails from frontend

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, email

I am trying to create a simple shortcode [resend_woo_emails].
This shortcode will create a form with a dropdown with all email classes, an input field for cc emails, and another input field for order_id (Later it could be a dropdown of all orders).

Here's my code so far -

```
function resend_woocommerce_emails_shortcode() {
 if ( isset( $_POST['email_resend_submit'] ) ) {
    $email_type = isset( $_POST['email_type'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email_type'] ) : '';
    $cc_emails = isset( $_POST['cc_emails'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cc_emails'] ) : '';
    $order_id = isset( $_POST['order_id'] ) ? absint( $_POST['order_id'] ) : '';

    $errors = array();
    // Handling all input errors

    // If no error
    if ( empty( $errors ) ) {
       // Getting all WC_emails array objects
       $mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

       // Send the email notification
       $mailer[$email_type]->trigger( $order_id );
    }
 }
 // Get all WooCommerce email classes
 $mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();
 $email_classes = array_keys( $mailer );

 // Output the form
 ob_start();

<form method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email_type">Select Email Type</label>
      <select name="email_type" id="email_type" class="form-control">
         <option value="">Select Email Type</option>
         <?php foreach ( $email_classes as $email_class ) : ?>
               <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $email_class ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $email_class ); ?></option>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
   </div>
    
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cc_emails">CC Email Addresses (separate multiple emails with commas)</label>
      <input type="text" id="cc_emails" name="cc_emails" class="form-control" />
   </div>
    
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="order_id">Order ID</label>
      <input type="number" id="order_id" name="order_id" class="form-control" />
   </div>
    
   <button type="submit" name="email_resend_submit" value="1">Resend Email</button>
</form>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

This is just the basic version but I am not receiving emails.
But I received email once... Don't know how.

I want to add the cc emails too like this - But still stuck at the first step as I am not receiving emails.

```
  // Add CC emails to the email recipients
  add_filter( "woocommerce_email_recipient_{$email_type}", function ( $recipient, $order ) use ( $cc_emails ) {
    return $recipient .= $cc_emails;
  }, 10, 2 );
```

Any help or guidance in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There is a missing ?> after ob_start() which I missed when copying code here.

Comment: If an order is in Processing, And I am trying to send On-Hold email - the email will not work, as the On-Hold email is not generated yet....
Does woo emails work like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... so this code actually works. The issue was you cannot resend an woo-commerce email that is not generated yet. And woo-commerce emails are generated only when status is changed.